# Aws-amplify invalid lambda function Invalid JSON response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I am using aws-amplify in a react native app for user signup and confirmation. For some reason, the `ConfirmSignUp` function returns an `InvalidLambdaResponseException`

```json
{
  "code": "InvalidLambdaResponseException",
  "message": "Invalid lambda function output: Invalid JSON",
  "name": "InvalidLambdaResponseException"
}
```

This is the snippet where I make the request. It's standard afaik.

```
try {
    await Auth.confirmSignUp(account.phone, account.verificationCode);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('authentication.confirmAccount', e);
    throw e;
  }
```

Everything else works fine. I have not been able to find any good information about how to resolve this error.

Versions:
`@aws-amplify/auth 3.4` and `@aws-amplify/core 2.8`

Comment: What does your signup request/response look like?

Comment: Please provide the code where the request fails.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Edit: I put the code in the original question.

Comment: are u getting the code successfully?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `PostConfirmation` trigger setup in Cognito, make sure your Lambda function returns the event as explained in this issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4341#issuecomment-840584718

Example of Lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // your code

  return event;
};
```